# Vhdl signal declaration usage

Tags: vhdl

I am a beginner in vhdl with not much grasp on signal.

My understanding is you can assign signal value such as
`signal<='100'` but you don't have to declare it. Is that correct?

Also, for sign extension `ext_imme<=(31 downto 16=> imme(15)) & imme;` why would this work for extending 16 bit to 32 bit by repeating `imme(15)` twice?

Comment: Your syntax isn't correct (`some_signal <= "100";` `signal` is a reserved word), nor your assumption. A named signal is always declared, that name may be a prefix for an implicit signal name, slice name or indexed name. An object is a type and a value, designated by it's declared name. The expression on the right hand side of the signal assignment to `ext_imme` contains an aggregate assigning an array length 15 with each element having the value of  imme(15) and concatenating that array with imme (presumably with a range 15 downto 0), producing an array value 32 long.  Show declarations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You can not assign signal value such as `signal<='100'` without declaring it it. You are not correct.

**VHDL doesn't like surprises.** Everything always must be declared before you use it.

So, you must declare a signal (in the *declarative region* of the `architecture`, ie between `architecture` and `begin`):

```
architecture SOME_NAME of SOME_OTHER_NAME is
  -- declare signals (and other things) here, eg
  signal SOME_SIGNAL_NAME : std_logic;  -- or some other type
begin
```

You can also initialise signals when you declare them, but I would be very careful doing this if you intend to synthesise the code, eg:

```
  signal SOME_SIGNAL_NAME : std_logic := '0';
```

2) This `ext_imme<=(31 downto 16=> imme(15)) & imme` is an example of an *aggregate* and a *concatenation*. An aggregate is a way of assigning to the elements of an array. A concatenation is a way of joining two arrays together to make a bigger array.

In your example, this is the aggregate: `(31 downto 16=> imme(15))`. Here you are making bits 31 down to 16 equal to bit 15 of `imme`. This gives you 16 bits all equal to bit 15 of `imme`.

The '&' operation is the *concatenation operator*. In your example, you are joining the 16 bits of the aggregate to the 16 bits of `imme` to make 32 bits in total.

Here some other examples of using aggregates: http://www.edaplayground.com/x/CQm.